# Запуск функции angularjs через greasemonkey

Tags: greasemonkey

Есть корпоративный сайт в котором есть кнопка с аттрибутом

```
ng-click="ams.openForm()"
```

Как мне запустить функцию openForm() с помощью greasemonkey? Если так и пишу:

```
ams.openForm()
```

то получаю ошибку

> ams is not defined

Как сделать так, что бы ams стал defined ?

Comment: Все необходимые библиотеки (включая angularjs) должны быть включены в само расширение.

Comment: Для greasemonkey - да, согласен, но если я запускаю указанную функцию через scratchpad то вижу указанную ошибку.